# Using day, Month or Year as MYSQL query filter in Laravel

Tags: laravel

In my code, i am querying a database by accepting month and year input from user.

I have tried writing it the normal PHP way and other ways i can find online but none seems to be working. here is the code i am using currently

```php
$salesmonth = $request->input('mn');
$salesyear = $request->input('yr');
$id = Auth::user()->id;
$comm = \DB::table('bakerysales')
    ->where([
        ['customer_id', '=', $id], [MONTH('sales_date'), '=', $salesmonth], [YEAR('sales_date
'), '=', $salesyear]
    ])
    ->get();

return view::make('showCommission')->with('comm', $comm);
```

I expect the query to return data from rows that match user selected month and year

Comment: What do you get if you var_dump `$salesyear` and `$salesmont`?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel comes with a few different [where clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses) for dealing with dates e.g.
 `whereDate` / `whereMonth` / `whereDay` / `whereYear`.

This means that your controller method can look something like:

```php
$comm = \DB::table('bakerysales')
    ->where('customer_id', auth()->id())
    ->whereMonth('sales_date', $request->input('mn'))
    ->whereYear('sales_date', $request->input('yr'))
    ->get();

return view('showCommission', compact('comm'));
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Ross. But I am getting an empty result from the DB. My input is supplying data OK. I can't seem to get my hands on why the query is returning empty as DB is populated

Comment: @Zeekstem Are the columns definitely `sales_date` and `sales_year`?

Comment: nope. The column is 'sales_date,. I made that correction in my code

Comment: Does changing the column to the correct one fix your issue?? If not, I would suggest commenting out each `where` clause one-by-one to see if one of those is the issue.

Comment: Ross, nope. It works fine if I take a number as user input instead of month name. So if user input is 4, it works. but if user input is March, it returns empty

Comment: @Zeekstem That will be because MySQL's `MONTH` function returns 1 to 12 i.e. `3 !== 'March'`. You will have to add your own logic in to convert a month name in to its numeric counterpart before you pass it to `whereMonth`.